Moments from characteristic function for matrices
When $x$ is a random variable with the smooth characteristic function $\phi_x(t) = \mathbb{E}e^{itx}$, we can easily compute the moments as $\mathbb{E}[x^k] = i^{-n}\phi_x^{(n)}(0)$. There is no magic here as this simply follows from power series expansion of the exponential function. Why is the picture not as clear in the case of random matrices?
More precisely, let $X$ be a random matrix. How do we obtain the moments $\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{Tr}(X^k)]$ (or $\mathbb{E}[X^k]$) from the characteristic function $\phi_X(T) = \mathbb{E} e^{i\operatorname{Tr}(T^*X)}$?
I expand the exponential and take successive directional derivatives with respect to $T$ but I have so far failed to find a clean relationship.
What is the use of characteristic function for matrix-valued random variables? Why would not we define a matrix-valued characteristic function, such as $\Phi_X(T) = \mathbb{E} e^{i T^*X}$?
